# PubNub Push Notifications

Tags: push-notification, pubnub

So I have push notifications setup. When several clients connect, and a message is pushed, each other client receives the message. This is good, but what I need is for Pubnub to be pushing to the person who sends the message aswell. How can I go about this?

I am using this function to listen. Is there some sort of option that I can specify so that I receive the notification aswell?

```
PUBNUB.subscribe({
    channel: "notify",
    callback: function(data) {
        alert(data.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'publishing' user also 'subscribing' ? This would enable him to receive the message as well.